# How do I access the onTextLayout event within a React Native Text component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native Text component that contains a user profile's information and has a max NumberOfLines at 2. I also have a TouchableOppacity button that says "Read More.." on it that clears the max NumberOfLines of the component. I don't want the "Read More" button to show if there the NumberOfLine is already 2 or less.

In the documentation it says that the onTextLayout event would return an array with a TextLayout objects for each line but when I try to access it I never have anything returned. I've tried to access the onLayout event and I can get info from that event but it doesn't have the info that I need. Has anyone had this problem?

```
<Text numberOfLines={2} onTextLayout={onInfoLayout}>
            test text test text test text test text
            test text test text test text test text
</Text> }


const onInfoLayout = React.useCallback((e:any) =>{
   console.log("this is how long the text is", e);
}, []);
```

The code above displays nothing in the console but if I were to change onTextLayout to just onLayout it would log the object.. but again that event doesn't have the info I need.

Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: Have you find a way? Cause `onTextLayout` never fires on my Text component for multilines usage.

Comment: I am stuck on this as well. Found any solutions Burismiga?

Answer (score 0):

The correct prop is `onLayout` according react native documentation here:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#onlayout

Comment: As per the op, this does not have the TextLayoutEvent prop, so not useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this issue. It seems you can't log the entire event object in the console because it has self-referential fields. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327432/logging-react-native-event-with-console-log-not-firing-and-eventually-crashes-th).